# Is it true for the symmetric matrices?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization

Suppose there are two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$. Then can we write $$\frac{tr(AB)}{B}=A$$ Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

The reason for question:

I am trying to understand an example from appendix A of convex optimization book (by Stephen Boyd). On page 642 it is written that $f(Z)\simeq f(X)+tr(X^{-1}(Z-X))$. Now the gradient of $f(X)$ is then shown to be $X^{-1}$. If I put $f(Z)$ in Equation A.4 then I have $$\frac{||f(Z)-f(X)-Df(X)(Z-X)||_{2}}{||Z-X||_2}=0$$ which results in $$tr(X^{-1}(Z-X))=Df(X)(Z-X)$$ Now if $tr(X^{-1}(Z-X))=X^{-1}(Z-X)$ then I can understand but I am not sure whether it is true or not. So any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you divide by a matrix..?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I suppose OP means matrix inverse, as the last equation suggests.

Comment: yes that is what I mean. I mean multiplying with the inverse

Comment: That's not true. There are many ways to make the trace zero.

Comment: @WeijunZhou thank you for your comment. But then how does the equation $tr(X^{-1}(Z-X))=Df(X)(Z-X)$ results in $Df(X)=X^{-1}$?

Comment: I don't have the book and I don't know what Equation A4 or $D$ is so I am sorry I cannot make further comment on this.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Equation A4 is the second equation in my original post and $Df(X)$ means derivative of $f(X)$ at $X$. Can you help me now. I can provide further detail if you want.

Comment: I am not sure. However one thing I have noticed is that in this case $Z-X$ can take many different values and the equation is true for all these values, which makes the problem different from what you asked in which $A$ and $B$ are just fixed matrices. Honestly I do not know how to go further.

Answer (score 2):

If $f:M_n (\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R $, then its derivative at $X $ is a linear map $Df(X):M_n (\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R $. What your text is saying is that in this case the map $Df (X) $ maps $$\tag1A \longmapsto\text {tr}(X^{-1}A) .$$

As every linear map $L:M_n (\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R $ is of the form $L (A)=\text {tr}\, (BA) $ for a matrix $B $, it is canonical to identify $L $ with $B $. With this in mind, is that we have the "equality" $$Df (X)=X^{-1}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can understand this if $X \in R^{n}$ but when $X \in S^{n}$ then I am unable to understand it. Can you provide detailed steps when $X \in S^{n}$. I will be very thankful to you

Comment: And even when $X \in R^{n}$ then the derivative will be $X^{-1}$ . How to invert a vector? I do not have any idea. But anyway in my problem the $X$ can only be a symmetric matrix

Comment: I wrote as if they were matrices, I'm editing that. Other than that, it is hard to tell because you provided no context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. According to the last equation in my post $$tr(X^{-1}(Z-X))=Df(X)(Z-X)$$ (please tell if this is right or wrong). If this is right then $Df(X)(Z-X)=<Df(X),(Z-X)>$ is to be proved. Right?

Comment: That's exactly what the left-hand-side means. There's nothing to prove.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Now the left hand side says $tr(X^{-1}(Z-X))=<X^{-1},Z-X>$ I can understand that. But on the right side how to prove that $Df(X)(Z-X)=<Df(X),Z-X>$. I hope I have clearly stated my problem.