# How to calculate the following $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log (\det X(x))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How to calculate the following

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \log (\det X(x))$$

where $X$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which is a function of $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Do you know how to express a determinant as a sum? It will be a step in the right direction (Jacobi's formula). Also know that "inner times outer" applies here as well.

Comment: @MichaelParis, no, I don't know. Would you please explain a little?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula. The determinant of a matrix has a couple of useful representations as a sum, one of which can be used to simplify your expression

Comment: relevant? [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137). Here I say 'We first note that for the case where the elements of X are independent, a constructive proof involving cofactor expansion and adjoint matrices can be made to show that $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ (Harville). This is not always equal to $2X^{-1}-diag(X^{-1})$. The fact alone that X is positive definite is sufficient to conclude that X is symmetric and thus its elements are not independent.' @MichaelParis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\log(\det(X(x))) = \frac{1}{\det(X(x))} \mathrm{Tr}\left(\mathrm{Adj}(X(x)) \mathrm{d} X(x)\right)
\end{equation}
Edit:

"d" implies the gradient operator in the covariant form, which acts on the provided (1,1)-tensor in the usual way, making it a (2,1)-tensor.

Comment: Do we have $X(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}log(det(X(x)))= tr(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}X(x))$

Comment: Is the result a vector or a matrix? What is the dimension of the result?

Comment: It's just in \mathrm{R}

Comment: $\mathrm{R}$? How it is possible that a derivative with respect to a vector becomes only in $\mathrm{R}$.?

Comment: Oh, my bad. Should be in R^d then. Didn't notice that x \in R^d.

Comment: So what is the correct form?

Comment: Please check the link in the comment to your question

Comment: Don't you correct your answer?

Comment: Please explain what is $d$ which you have replaced instead of $\partial$? Sorry, I am not an expert.

Comment: relevant? [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137). Here I say 'We first note that for the case where the elements of X are independent, a constructive proof involving cofactor expansion and adjoint matrices can be made to show that $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ (Harville). This is not always equal to $2X^{-1}-diag(X^{-1})$. The fact alone that X is positive definite is sufficient to conclude that X is symmetric and thus its elements are not independent.'

Answer (score 2):

The [gradient of $\log \det X$ with respect to the entries of $X$ is $X^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447692/why-the-gradient-of-log-detx-is-x-1-and-where-did-trace-tr-go), so the total derivative with respect to $x$ is $\sum_i \sum_j (X^{-1}(x))_{ij} (X'_{ij}(x))$. Here, $X_{ij}(x)$ denotes the $i,j$-entry of $X(x)$, and $X'_{ij}$ denotes the derivative of this entry with respect to $x$. $X^{-1}(x)$ denotes the matrix inverse of $X(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Although it must be very easy, I'm a little confused. Could you please show it in matrix notation form?

Comment: relevant? [Prove $\frac{\partial \rm{ln}|X|}{\partial X} = 2X^{-1} - \rm{diag}(X^{-1})$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1493137). Here I say 'We first note that for the case where the elements of X are independent, a constructive proof involving cofactor expansion and adjoint matrices can be made to show that $\frac{\partial ln|X|}{\partial X} = X^{-T}$ (Harville). This is not always equal to $2X^{-1}-diag(X^{-1})$. The fact alone that X is positive definite is sufficient to conclude that X is symmetric and thus its elements are not independent.'